# Why doesn't the Nernst Equation match my data at low values of Q?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, nernst-equation

I have formatted my data below in a table so my issue is more clear and asked this question again, I apologize for any confusion. I don't understand why the low values of Q are inaccurate while the high values are accurate. I saw online that the Nernst equation doesn't work for high concentrations, but why would high concentrations of ZnSO4 work while high concentrations of CuSO4 wouldn't? I also wanted to use high concentrations since when I did the Q = 1 trial with 2 0.01 M solutions instead of 0.1 M, I got around 1.08 V instead of 1.1 V which I assume is due to resistance. Other factors like the salt bridge's solution and concentration, volume of solutions used, and temperature were kept constant. I also spent a while waiting every time for the solution's voltage to slowly increase until it stabilized, although for the 3 trials that were accurate, they didn't take more than 10 seconds to reach the expected while the others would slowly increase for upwards of 2 minutes. I made sure to sand the metal before use. I couldn't find any other information online so I would greatly appreciate any help!

| Increment # | Concentrations, M | Ratio of Concentrations, Q | Theoretical Voltage, V | Experimental Voltage, V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Increment 1 | ZnSO4=0.01 M, CuSO4=1.00 M | Q = 0.01 | 1.158 | 1.115 |
| Increment 2 | ZnSO4=0.10 M, CuSO4=1.00 M | Q = 0.10 | 1.129 | 1.110 |
| Increment 3 | ZnSO4=0.10 M, CuSO4=0.10 M | Q = 1.00 | 1.100 | 1.098 |
| Increment 4 | ZnSO4=1.00 M, CuSO4=0.10 M | Q = 10.0 | 1.071 | 1.073 |
| Increment 5 | ZnSO4=1.00, CuSO4=0.01 | Q = 100 | 1.042 | 1.041 |

Here is a graph to visualize the problem too:
[image]

Comment: Have you deleted your prior question?

Comment: Yes, but I still have it visible. I saw your answer saying that the concentrations were too high and you asked if I observed a drift. Can I ask what you mean by drift?

Comment: I can restore the question if you would like. I am wondering why the Nernst equation only fails for high concentrations of CuSO4 and not ZnSO4. Also, why does the equation predict the Q=1 trial when the concentrations of both solutions are  0.1 M but not 0.01 M even though it should be the opposite?

Comment: Generally speaking you should attempt to edit a question (there is a button at the bottom of the post for this) but do not reopen your older post now.

Comment: Ok, I have it closed now. Do I just wait for others to answer my question?